# Использование итераторов для проверки элементов массива

Tags: ruby, итераторы

```
def isfin?
  @matrix[0..@col_count-1][0]==0
end
```

Как пользоваться итераторами в Ruby? Например, нужно вернуть `true`, если все элементы массива [n][0] (где `n` от `0` до "длина массива - 1") равны нулю. Или в данном случае лучше использовать простой цикл?

Например, если у нас будет `0..200`, и на второй позиции уже не `0`, то можно выйти с `false` и не просматривать остальные элементы. Или при использовании итераторов это условие будет автоматически учтено, и медленнее работать не будет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, судя по собаке, речь идет о методе собственного класса. Я бы рекомендовал не воротить никакого ООП, пока не знаешь сам язык и stdlib.

```
def isfin?
  @matrix.all? do |row|
    row[0] == 0
  end
end
```

Итератор `all?` здесь обрывается и возвращает `false` как только блок `do end` вернет `false`.

Можно переписать это таким образом, что матрицу сначала транспонируем, и проверяем лишь одномерный массив:

```
def isfin?
  @matrix.transpose.first.all? do |cell|
    cell == 0
  end
end
```

И тогда использование стандартного метода `.zero?` позволяет записать это короче:

```
def isfin?
  @matrix.transpose.first.all? &:zero?
end
```

А можно `.map` вместо `.tranpose` использовать -- это может работать быстрей:

```
def isfin?
  @matrix.map(&:first).all? &:zero?
end
```

Comment: Здорово! Большое спасибо за такой обзорчик, очень познавательно!